# How to return a new dataframe where numbers represent a percent of their containing row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Using Python and Pandas I have a dataframe that is filled with numerical values. What I am trying to do, and can't figure out is how do I return a new data frame where each number represents a percentage of that row

Essentially what I need is to return a new data frame where the numbers from the old data frame are changed to represent the % they represent of that specific row as a whole. Hope that makes sense.

Below is an example of the starting data frame, each row would total 10 to make the example easy and simple

```
             ambivalent   negative   neutral  positive
11/15/2021       6          2             1       1
11/8/2021        4          1             2       3
```

what I want to achieve is this

```
                 ambivalent   negative   neutral  positive
11/15/2021       60%          20%           10%       10%
11/8/2021        40%          10%           20%       30%
```

I don't need the actual % symbol just the actual percent numbers will work.

Can someone point me in the right direction in how to do this?

Comment: Just divide by row sums: `new_df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)` you can multiply by 100 if needed too `new_df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100`

Comment: If you really wanted the percent could do `new_df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).astype(str).add('%')` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989890/15497888)

Comment: You could also play with the display settings instead of making them strings if you need the numerical values for computation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671975/15497888) and [Options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method with a lambda function:

```
result = df.apply(lambda row: row/sum(row)*100,axis=1)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,3],'b':[3,5],'c':[5,2]})
result = df.apply(lambda row: row/sum(row),axis=1)
```

`df` is:

```
   a  b  c
0  2  3  5
1  3  5  2
```

`result` is:

```
      a     b     c
0  20.0  30.0  50.0
1  30.0  50.0  20.0
```